# Can we customize ionic toast close button.?

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic4

I am trying to add background color for ionic toast button but couldn't succeed. I tried below css in global.scss. Could someone tell me how can I achieve this.?

```
  .positive-toast-message {
       --min-width: 60%;
       --background: #bde7c3;
       --color: black;
       --button-color: black;
       .toast-button {
        --background: red !important;
        background: white !important;
        background-color: blue !important;
       }
   }
```

Once Toast is created, it is applying 'positive-toast-message' css properly

Answer (score 3):

If you want to do that, then you should use css class.
Call the toast like this

```
const toast = await this.toastCtrl.create({
    message: 'Please Fill all fields',
    duration: 30000,
    position: 'top',
    cssClass: 'toast-bg'
  });

  toast.present();
```

Then go to global.scss file and put this class there

```
.toast-bg {
  --background: blue;
  --button-color: #ffffff;
}
```

This should work. change the color to whatever color you want within the css class in global.scss

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This works fine to change background color for TOAST. I am looking to override toast's BUTTON background color.

Comment: @Deepak To change the buttons color just change the background style of the button to what ever suits you, like this: style="background: blue;"  put that within the button tag, or you can just put "background: blue;" within a class and call the class within the button tag

Comment: @PraiseHart have you even tried the code you suggested? You should know you cannot "put that within the button tag" in a toast. Also, "background: blue within a class" does not work either.
Deepak did you solve this?

Comment: @afe Yes I've worked on toasts with the code I suggested and it worked perfectly fine. If using a normal HTML button tag, you can add a style attribute to it as I suggested and then change the background color to whatever color you want like so: <button style="background: red;" type="button" onclick="myFunction()" > Click Me! </button>  but if using ionic button tag, you can either use the style attribute like I showed for HTML button tag or you can create a css class to change the background color and then add the class to the ion-buttons tag

Comment: @Deepak if you meant the buttons within the toast popup then you can change that by adding: --button-color: #ffffff; to the toast-bg cssClass

Answer (score 2):

On IONIC 5 you can simply use CSS shadow and toast part to apply your customization.

for example, in order to change the button's color you can simply use the below code:

```html
ion-toast::part(button) {
  --button-color: var(--ion-color-tertiary) !important;
  --color: var(--ion-color-tertiary) !important;
}
```